# Delay function to slow down while loop

Tags: matlab, function, pause

I'm new to MATLAB and I've got a question to ask. I am currently doing up this UI which includes a code which is shown below.

```
% --- Executes on button press in Start.
function Start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)  
% hObject    handle to Start (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global s brightness a t;
t = 0.1
a = 1;
readasync(s);
while (a == 1) 
  brightness = str2double(fscanf(s, '%s', 8));
  set(handles.brightness, 'String', num2str(brightness));
  disp(brightness);
 if brightness < 87
    if brightness < 44
       fprintf(s, '%s',1);
    else
       fprintf(s,'%s',2);
    end
 else
    if brightness < 130
       fprintf(s, '%s',3);
    else
       fprintf(s, '%s',4);
    end
 end
 if(a==0)
     break;
 end  
   pause(1/10);
end
```

As you can see, I am currently using a pause function to delay the while loop. However my mentor in college suggested that I use tic toc instead of pause to delay the loop. I do not know how should I go about with it. He has given me this function but I do not know how to implement it. Any advice?

```
function delay(t)
tic;
while toc < t
end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you necessarily want to delay your while loop, but `pause()` is fine to use if you want to do that. Your mentor should of looked up what [`tic toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) does, it's to measure performance of code. It does not delay or pause at all.

Comment: I do understand that tic toc is to only measure performance of the code. However, he has told me that pause is unreliable and use tic toc instead. I really do not understand it

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek while tic/toc is primarily used for first blush profiling, `tic` can certainly be used with a `while` loop as an alternative to `pause`.

Comment: I would suggest using a [`timer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) if you don't believe that `pause` is sufficient for your needs.

Comment: how to do use tic as an alternative to pause in the while loop?

Comment: Use `delay` instead of `pause`.

Comment: Commenters should note that `pause` will flush the graphics and callback queues, and is not equivalent to the `delay` function suggested. In the context of a GUI that might be an important difference, and there may well be a good reason for using the `delay` rather than `pause`.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `pause(1/10)`, just write `delay(1/10)` instead. They are not quite the same thing, as `pause` has a side effect of flushing any graphics updates and GUI callbacks that may have queued up.

Answer (score 0):

As excaza indicated you can replace the line `pause(1/10);` by `delay(1/10);` but the function `delay` must be visible to where it is being called (so for example you can create a file in the same directory called `delay.m` that contains the code from your mentor).

It might be helpful to point out that replacing the code `pause(1/10);` by `tic; while toc < 1/10 end;` accomplishes the same thing functionally, even though this isn't as good from a coding practice/readability perspective.

Comment: `pause` is not functionally equivalent to the `delay` function suggested by the OP’s mentor. `pause` also flushes the graphics and callback queues, which in the context of a GUI may well be quite an important difference.